# Accessing text file contained in .NET Core single file executable

Tags: .net-core

I created a .NET Core 3.1 console application that contains a default appsettings.json configuration file in the same directory as the executable. When the application starts up, it will look for the configuration in the users' `AppData/Local/<appname>` folder, and if the application cannot find the configuration file there, it will copy the default configuration file to the local AppData folder.

This works fine, but I would like to distribute the application as a single executable file (using `dotnet publish /p:PublishSingleFile=true ...`). The problem is I cannot access the default configuration file anymore. When I open the single published file in a hex editor, I can see the content of the default configuration in there, so I know the default configuration file is somehow included in the published single file.

Is it at all possible to access included files while publishing the application as a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the self-contained executable starts, the first thing it does is to extract its content to a temporary directory. This is documented [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3668#issuecomment-535555170).

As for getting the path of the temporary folder itself, where all your files will be extracted, just use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)` as referenced [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13051#issuecomment-550060931).